# react JS with firebasestore db not creating docSnap after signing in with redirect. But creating docSnap when signing in with popup

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-signin

Newbie here. I am trying to create sign in with google with react JS and firebasestore db. The issue is it is not creating a docSnap when using signInWithRedirect but works fine when using signInWithPopup. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

```
 const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(getAuth(), (user) => {
      if (user && user.verified) {
        navigate("/");
      } else if (user && !user.verified) {
        navigate("/additional-info");
      }
    });
  });

  const { userData } = useUser();

  async function onGoogleSignIn() {
    try {
      let data = {
        uid: "",
        email: "",
        verified: false,
        name: "",
      };
      if (isMobile) {
        const auth = getAuth();
        const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

        const resultRef = await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);

        console.log(resultRef.user);
        data.uid = resultRef.user.uid;
        data.verified = false;
        data.name = resultRef.user.displayName;
        data.email = resultRef.user.email;

        userData(data);

        // check for the user if in the db
        const userRef = resultRef.user;
        const docRef = doc(db, "users", userRef.uid);
        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

        if (!docSnap.exists()) {
          // add the user to the db
          await setDoc(doc(db, "users", userRef.uid), {
            displayName: userRef.displayName,
            email: userRef.email,
            uid: userRef.uid,
            timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
          });
          navigate("/additional-info");
        }
      } else {
        const auth = getAuth();
        const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
        const resultRef = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);

        data.uid = resultRef.user.uid;
        data.verified = false;
        data.name = resultRef.user.displayName;
        data.email = resultRef.user.email;

        userData(data);

        // check for the user if in the db
        const userRef = resultRef.user;
        const docRef = doc(db, "users", userRef.uid);
        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

        if (!docSnap.exists()) {
          // add the user to the db
          await setDoc(doc(db, "users", userRef.uid), {
            displayName: userRef.displayName,
            email: userRef.email,
            uid: userRef.uid,
            timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
          });
          navigate("/additional-info");
        }
      }

      navigate("/additional-info");
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("Could not sign in with google");
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col my-3">
      <button
        onClick={onGoogleSignIn}
        type="button"
        className="flex items-center justify-center bg-red-500 text-white rounded-md p-2 hover:bg-red-600 active:bg-red-700"
      >
        Continue with Google
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

trying to sign in with google and create docSnap if it does not exists. works fine when using signInWithPopup but does not create docSnap when doing signInWithRedirect.